# How to work with several view sections in a single layout (Ember)?

Tags: events, layout, view, ember.js, show-hide

I'm trying to create an application which has a content view and a sidebar to the left. I'm having trouble understanding how I should implement the Menu which resides in the sidebar. Naturally I would like it to be it's own module with a controller and everything but I've been finding a lot of issues that arise when trying this. My application template has an outlet where I put the content and I include the menu with `{{view}}` but then I can't connect it to the controller which it belongs to.

I've tried the solution proposed at http://jsfiddle.net/tzYE7/7/ and it will let me access the properties of the controller, but the events doesn't get executed. Then I tried integrating the menu into the `ApplicationController` instead but that doesn't seem very elegant and rather messy. I also would like to connect a model to the menu and I believe that this would get pretty confusing if I try to incorporate all this in `ApplicationController`. The things is that I don't want the menu to simply be static, I would like to be able to hide and show it on command.

I'm pretty new to the framework and I'm trying to wrap my head around it's workflow and how to connect all the bits and pieces. Any idea on how to do this properly?

**Edit:**

> "the emple jsfiddle you have provided is using the the old router, can
>   you actually post your current code, this will make it easier to help
>   out" – intuitivepixel

Since it's a more of a framework related question and not regarding my code I figured it wasn't really neccessary, but I will try to elaborate further.

What I got is basically an application template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
   <aside id="sidebar">
      {{view App.MenuView}}
   </aside>
   <section id="content>
      {{outlet}}
   </section>
</script>
```

What I first discovered was that no controller properties was accessible in the Menu-template. I found this mentioned in the following in a github issue (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1712) that's also where I found a reference to the jsfiddle that suggested that I connected the controller within the view that was inserted:

```
App.MenuView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'menu',

  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.set("controller", App.MenuController.create());
  }
});
```

However, No events are delegated to `MenuController`, so something is still not working. That was when I tried integrating everything into `ApplicationController` instead.

What is the standard way of doing this in Ember? I also want to be able to hide/show the menu from other controllers in the application but it seems like the other controllers must depend on the Menu controller for that to work, can't it be done with events instead?

That's basically what I'm wondering. Thank you for your time and knowledge! :)

Comment: the emple jsfiddle you have provided is using the the old router, can you actually post your current code, this will make it easier to help out

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? Please share if you had. Am interested to know

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't been working with Ember for a while and I never solved this issue